# Spring Boot API does not show updated data from MongoDB database

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have made an API in Spring Boot that connects to a MongoDB localhost database. The database has two collections 'movies' and 'reviews'. The API uses 'movies' collection to fetch movies using a GET request. The Movie object in API consists a List of Review objects which will be displayed as `reviewIds` list in JSON as a API response for fetching all the movies. Each movie object consists of such `reviewIds` list. When I use GET request, it fetches all the movies correctly. When I use POST request to update the `reviewIds` list by inserting a Review object, the DB shows changes successfully done too. But now if I try to use that GET request to see the movies collection through API request, it still shows `reviewIds` list as empty whereas it appears perfectly updated in the database.

#### MovieController.java:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/movies")
public class MovieController {

    private final MovieService movieService;

    MovieController(MovieService movieService) {
        this.movieService = movieService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> getAllMovies() {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Movie>>(movieService.allMovies(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{imdbId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Movie>> getSingleMovie(@PathVariable String imdbId) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Optional<Movie>>(movieService.singleMovie(imdbId), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

#### MovieService.java:

```
@Service
public class MovieService {

    private final MovieRepository movieRepository;

    MovieService(MovieRepository movieRepository) {
        this.movieRepository = movieRepository;
    }

    public List<Movie> allMovies() {
        return movieRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<Movie> singleMovie(String imdbId) {
        return movieRepository.findMovieByImdbId(imdbId);
    }

}
```

#### ReviewController.java:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/reviews")
public class ReviewController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ReviewService reviewService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Review> createReview(@RequestBody Map<String, String> payload)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<Review>(reviewService.createReview(payload.get("reviewBody"), payload.get("imdbId")), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } 
}
```

#### ReviewService.java:

```
@Service
public class ReviewService {

    @Autowired
    private ReviewRepository reviewRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public Review createReview(String reviewBody, String imdbId) {
        Review review = reviewRepository.insert(new Review(reviewBody));
        mongoTemplate.update(Movie.class).matching(Criteria.where("imdbId").is(imdbId)).apply(
                new Update().push("reviewIds").value(review)).first();

        return review;
    }

}
```

I tried using GSON dependency to print the JSON response directly in Java and it also shows the list as empty only. So the problem is definitely not in using InsomniaAPI or Chrome I guess.

## updated database:

[image: reviewIds list is updated through POST request]

## API response after updated list in the database:

[image: reviewIds list is still shown as empty here]

Answer (score 0):

I had written 'reviewsIds' in constructor, getters & setters and also in the update function whereas my movies collection has 'reviewIds'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).